# What did replace Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

It looks like Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB is archived https://github.com/amazon-archives/dynamodb-geo so, was it deprecated, obsoleted, abandoned? Did anything replaced it for making geospatial searches DynamoDB? Did Amazon developed another one? Implemented as a feature on their own libraries or something else I'm missing?

Comment: For the voting to close: I'm not asking for recommendations. I'm asking if the creator of the library, Amazon, specifically did something else like create another library I'm not finding or implement it in their core client libraries.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?